# XAMPP Windows 10 - Could not find your craft/ folder error

Tags: install, installation

I'm new to Craft CMS and would like to getting started, I searched for several hours now but I was not able to find an answer.

I downloaded and copied craft to my htdocs folder, created a database and changed the db access but when I open my page I get

```
Could not find your craft/ folder. Please ensure that $craftPath is set correctly in C:\xampp\htdocs\craft\public\index.php
```

I think I have to change the permission of that folder but I have no idea how to do this. Could you help me?

I didn't change any path, so it is correct and points to the right file but there is only one directory visible in `C:\xampp\htdocs\craft\` in my browser

Edit:
my Files looks like this
`htdocs`
`-craft`
`--craft`
`---app`
`---config`
`---plugins`
`---storage`
`---templates`
`---.htaccess`
`---web.config`
`--public`
`---index.php`

Comment: Can you maybe edit your original question and post a screenshot of what your folder structure looks like? i.e. where does the `craft/app` folder sit in relation to `public/index.php`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you've got craft within htdocs, so your web server is trying to run craft from the root, instead of where it should be, `/public`

To illustrate, this is where htdocs *should* be.

```
-craft

--craft
---app
---config
---plugins
---storage
---templates
---.htaccess
---web.config

--public <- htdocs
---index.php
```

I suggest, to test, that you change the httpd.conf to make apache run from the public folder rather than the pre-made htdocs folder xampp has given you. Go into the xampp config, click on `httpd.conf` and change the following lines:

[image]

`DocumentRoot "your\path\to\htdocs\craft\public"`

and

`<Directory "your\path\to\htdocs\craft\public">`

Restart your server, and you should be golden. On windows, you shouldn't have any permission issues with folders.

As an example, here is what my lines look like:

```
DocumentRoot "D:\Documents\work\bud\public"
<Directory "D:\Documents\work\bud\public">
```

I'd avoid just dumping the code in the pre-made htdocs folder provided and just route your httpd.conf to wherever your codebase is.